# SDL2 relative mouse mode reporting motion when mouse has not been moved

Tags: sdl-2

I'm new to SDL2, so pardon any ignorance, but I am experiencing strange results when using relative mouse mode in SDL2.0.3. When I do `SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_bool::SDL_true)`, the cursor is hidden as expected. Inside the event loop, I check for `windowEvent.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION` and then use `windowEvent.motion.xrel/yrel`  `xrel` and `yrel` report values from -4 to 4 when the mouse is not even moving! Furthermore, actually moving my mouse does not seem to correlate whatsoever to the `xrel` and `yrel`'s being reported.

Should I be doing this differently?

Comment: Please show a minimal example reproducing the behaviour.

Comment: Did you check the return value of `SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode` to ensure it is supported. It will return -1 if relative mouse mode is not supported. As silly as this may sound, have you tested a different mouse? An 8 pixel spread could be the result of defective mouse input.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to see what the issue actually is - and it does appear to be related to the mouse. When I run my program on a laptop using the track pad, the issue seems to go away. However, when I use the mouse I've been testing with, there is a huge delay between moving the mouse and having it show up in the motion events. Furthermore, once they do show up, the program executes the movement very slowly. Any ideas why this might be? My shaders are very small so I don't expect it's a GPU overload issue.

Comment: Is it possible you're only handling one event per frame, then using vsync or otherwise limiting frame rate? That could cause a backlog; you want to do SDL_PollEvent in a loop until it returns false, for each frame.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem on my computer, but using `Uint32 SDL_GetRelativeMouseState(int* x,int* y)` instead works fine.

Comment: I had the same problem on **SDL 2.0.12** and confirm that `SDL_GetRelativeMouseState()` resolve the "noise" of event `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` with `motion.xrel` and `motion.yrel`

Comment: Does anyone know why this is? Because it was working fine for me on 2.0.20, but once I upgraded to 2.26.3 I had the same issue and had to use SDL_GetRelativeMouseState() to fix it